# Displaying information based on selected item in selectfield

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I was wondering if it is possible to display a link that is associated with the option in the select field that the user selects. I am currently using a database to store the options and have a category in the database per option where "extra" information is stored.  I was thinking that the extra information could be the link about the selected item.  However,
I am unsure how to display this link as the user selects the item in the select field. I would also like the link to change when a different item is selected.
I am currently using Flask, Flask-WTF, Flask-sqlalchemy, HTML , and jsonify.

Comment: Just selected, not submitted, right? You'll need to hang a `change` event listener onto your select field and change the link yourself accordingly.

Comment: Yes just selected.  Sorry I am quite a beginner at this, would you mind going more in depth?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fruits = {
  "1": { "colour": "yellow", "shape": "long" },
  "2": { "colour": "red", "shape": "round" }
};

const fruitSelect = document.getElementById('fruit');

function setFruitOptions() {
  if (fruitSelect.selectedIndex !== -1) {
    const fruit = fruits[fruitSelect.options[fruitSelect.selectedIndex].value];
    document.getElementById('shape').textContent = fruit.shape;
    document.getElementById('colour').textContent = fruit.colour;
  }
}
 
fruitSelect.addEventListener('change', setFruitOptions);
setFruitOptions();
```

```html
<select id="fruit">
  <option value="1">banana</option>
  <option value="2">apple</option>
</select>
is <span id="shape"></span> and <span id="colour"></span>.
```

You can deliver the necessary JS object in Flask using something like this in the template:

```
<script>
  const fruits = {{ fruit_dict|tojson|safe }};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you.  Could you clear up a few things for me?  I am currently using Flask and my choices are in the Python file using flask to display the choices and not in Javascript.  I was wondering if you could help me implement with Flask. I see that you have provided an example with flask, but I am not sure what that means.

Comment: You don't have enough details for me to do anything else. You can render your select field however you wish, including the Flask template. The important bit is the JavaScript, that changes other elements in accordance to your selection choice.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, which part is the JS, the top part?  Is there a way I can show you my code, sorry I am new to this site